# How to create tree from JSON without recursion and any library javascript

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I get JSON string. And use function for create ul list.

How i can do it without recursion?

Thank anyone for help!

```
function createJsonTree(objData) {
    if (isChild(objData))
        return;

    var ul = createElem('ul');

    for (var i = 0, length = objData.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (i in objData) {
            var li = createElem('li');

            if (objData[i].dropmenu) {
                ...
            }

            var li = createElem('li');
            li.innerHTML = objData[i].NAMEGROUP;

            var childUl = createJsonTree(objData[i].dropmenu);

            if (childUl)
                li.appendChild(childUl);

            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    }

    return ul;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a tree without recursion? How do you plan on *using* a tree without recursion?

Comment: You can use a stack instead and iterate.

Comment: anything done recursively can be done iteratively. might end up being hideously ugly/inefficient, but doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: Because I want to learn to do it without recursion.
With the help of the cycle, but does not work yet (

Comment: @GanibalKing: Hint: recursion manages the stack/queue structure for you by using the call stack. If you want to do something recursive in a loop instead you need to manually manage the stack/queue using an array.

Comment: Thank you all! I will write a diploma, and I will try ...

Answer (score 1):

For "breath-first traversing", use a queue (first in first out).  For "depth-first traversing", use a stack (last in first out)

Here is the pseudo code

```
// add the root node to the structure
// while the structure has elements in it
//    withdraw first element
//    add all it's children to the structure
//    do something with the element
```